# Bundle install fails to install my gem fork on GitHub

Tags: rubygems, github, bundler

On GitHub, I made a fork of a gem [adammck-rubygsm](https://github.com/adammck/rubygsm). My fork is here https://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm.

I want to switch my application from the original to my forked gem. So, in Gemfile I changed the line

```
gem 'adammck-rubygsm'
```

to

```
gem 'adammck-rubygsm', :git => "git://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm.git"
```

When I run "bundle install", I get the following failure

```
$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'adammck-rubygsm (>= 0)' in git://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'adammck-rubygsm (>= 0)'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried replacing rubygsm with adammck-rubygsm in your rubygsm.gemspec file? For the s.name variable. Or it may be replacing gem 'adammck-rubygsm' with gem 'khwang1-rubygsm' in the Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The s.name in the original gem and my fork have always been "rubygsm". I did make the change in my Gemfile from "gem 'adammck-rubygsm'" to "gem 'rubygsm'", and that did help a little.

Answer (score 2):

The `git` directive has to be specified with https, as in:

```
gem 'resque', :require => "resque/server", git: 'https://github.com/defunkt/resque.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I made the following changes in order to successfully bundle install [my fork of adammck-rubygsm](https://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm) from GitHub:

- in my application Gemfile, change to `gem 'rubygsm', :git => "git://github.com/khwang1/rubygsm.git"`. The s.name in the Gem's .gemspec has always been "rubygsm".

Then, bundle install complains could not find gem 'toholio-serialport'

- in my fork gem's .gemspec, remove the line `s.add_dependency("toholio-serialport", ["> 0.7.1"])`. Commit and push the change to GitHub.

Bundle install complains `rubygsm did not have a valid gemspec...The validation message from Rubygems was: ["bin/gsm-app-monitor"] are not files`

- examine the gem source cod, the file bin/gsm-app-monitor indeed doesn't exist. In my fork gem's .gemspec file , remove  `"bin/gsm-app-monitor"` from `s.files`. Commit and push the change to GitHub.

Now, bundle install successfully installs gem rubygsm from my fork gem on GitHub!

Answer (score 0):

The gemspec of your fork might contain a different name to that of the gem on RubyGems, for example when I forked active_merchant on GitHub their `.gemspec` file had:

```
s.name         = 'activemerchant'
```

but the gem is defined as active_merchant on RubyGems so I changed my Gemfile from:

```
gem "active_merchant", git: "https://github.com/adamwaite/active_merchant.git", require: "active_merchant"
```

to:

```
gem "activemerchant", git: "https://github.com/adamwaite/active_merchant.git", require: "active_merchant"
```

note the lack of "_".

Everything worked perfectly after that. This may be an obscure case, but I hope it helps someone!